# Obtener un valor de archivo .csv y generar un grafico

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo que hacer un programa en el cual ingrese un pais y me devuelva un grafico de los casos de covid en ese pais durante un tiempo mediante un grafico,

Usando python 3 con pandas tengo que buscar en un archivo .csv en una columna Pais el cual puede estar repetido mas de una vez, y conseguir un dato por cada vez que se repita el pais en otra columna, con esos datos que son numericos deberia generar una lista para poder hacer un grafico, tengo 2 problemas, el primero es que no puedo obtener el resultado sin indice y el segundo es que no puedo meterlo en una lista, evidentemente estoy teniendo un problema con los tipos de datos.
Seria algo asi: 
Pais   ----------   Casos  ----    Fecha 
Argentina-------4------2020-10-12 
Argentina------    3------2020-10-13  
Chile ------------ 3 ----2020-8-10
etc.

```html
datos = pd.read_csv("full_data.csv", index_col= "location")
data = datos.to_dict("list")
print("Cargando base de datos")

def unPais(dato):

    x = []
    y = []
    
    paiselige = input("Seleccionar pais")
    new_cases = datos["new_cases"][paiselige]
    new_cases = new_cases.to_csv(index = False)
    
    for i in range(len(new_cases)):
      x.append(new_cases[i])
```

Si hago print(new_cases) me da los valores correspondientes tipo float, pero cuando los quiero meter con el for en x y le doy print me da algo como esto:

```
'new_cases\r\n1.0\r\n1.0\r\n6.0\r\n1.0\r\n3.0\r\n""\r\n7.0\r\n""\r\n12.0\r\n3.0\r\n11.0\r\n11.0\r\n9.0\r\n14.0\r\n18.0\r\n31.0\r\n30.0\r\n67.0\r\n41.0\r\n35.0\r\n86.0\r\n115.0\r\n87.0\r\n101.0\r\n55.0\r\n75.0\r\n146.0\r\n0.0\r\n167.0\r\n0.0\r\n132.0\r\n186.0\r\n103.0. \
```

Se me quemaron los papeles, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este script ingresas el país y te gráfica los casos por fecha:

```
# Importando librerias
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Cargando el archivo
df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv", sep=";")


# Cambiando el tipo de dato en fecha
df["Fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Fecha"],format='%Y-%m-%d')



# Creando función
def funcion_graficar(pais):

    #Filtrando el pais
    df_filtrado = df[df["Pais"] == pais]
    
    
    if df_filtrado.shape[0] == 0:
    print("Pais no encontrado!!")
    else:
    # Graficando
    df_filtrado.plot(x ='Fecha', y='Casos', kind = 'bar')

# Corriendo función que genera la gráfica

pais = input("Ingrese el pais: ")
funcion_graficar(pais)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Para próximas preguntas pega capturas de pantalla de tus dataframes para ver como están formado.*

No entiendo muy bien para que hiciste varias cosas en tu código, pero si toda la información está en un sólo **csv** y si estás usando **pandas** podrías hacer algo así:

```
datos = pd.read_csv("full_data.csv")
nuevoDf = datos.loc[datos["pais"]=="Argentina",["pais","casos", "fecha"]]
```

Con [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) seleccionas todas las filas de un país (en el ejemplo, Argentina), luego de éste sub-dataframe seleccionas sólo las columnas que te interesan (en el ejemplo "pais", "casos" y "fecha").
Para graficarlo podrías guardar este nuevoDf en un archivo csv

```
nuevoDf.to_csv('casos.csv')
```

o podrías usar [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).
Si lo estás haciendo solo de forma educativa te recomiendo que uses matplotlib y [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/)